# How can I loop and push an array into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to simplify my codes by using loop

```
let tmpD = [];
let tmpS0 = [];
let tmpS1 = [];
let tmpS2 = [];

signed = doctors.doc(tmpD[0].key).collection('schedule').get();
signed.then(function(ss){
  ss.forEach(function(schedule){
    tmpS0.push(schedule.data());
  });
  console.log(tmpS0)
});
signed = doctors.doc(tmpD[1].key).collection('schedule').get();
signed.then(function(ss){
  ss.forEach(function(schedule){
    tmpS1.push(schedule.data());
  });
  console.log(tmpS1)
});
signed = doctors.doc(tmpD[2].key).collection('schedule').get();
signed.then(function(ss){
  ss.forEach(function(schedule){
    tmpS2.push(schedule.data());
  });
  console.log(tmpS2)
});
```

I've tried using for loop like `for(var i = 0; i < tmpD.length; i++)` above the first signed and pushed the data to `tmpS` and it turns out it pushed everything to a single array. I also tried pushing the array to `tmpS[i]` but it caused an error.

Comment: Which lanaguage are you using (JavaScript)? Could you provide definition of the `doctors`? How is `tmpD` initialized?

Comment: I do not see `tmpS` array. Also what error are you getting?

Comment: to @Mr.Nimelo sir `firebase.firestore().collection('doctors')`. I'm using typescript.

Comment: @Rajesh I'm trying to make it to `tmpS` instead of using `tmpS0`, `tmpS1` and `tmpS2`. If you can help me do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a 2D array of `tmpS0`, `tmpS1` etc and update them based on the index:

```
let tmpD = [];
let tmpS0 = [];
let tmpS1 = [];
let tmpS2 = [];

let tmps = [tmpS0, tmpS1, tmpS2];

tmpD.forEach(({ key }, i) => {
  const signed = doctors.doc(key).collection('schedule').get();
  signed.then(function(ss) {
    ss.forEach(function(schedule) {
      tmps[i].push(schedule.data());
    });
    console.log(tmps[i])
  });
})
```

**Update:**

If the variables are dynamic, you can just create the `tmpS` array and keep pushing to it based on the index of `tmpD` array:

```
let tmpD = [];
let tmpS = []; // 2D array

tmpD.forEach(({ key }, i) => {
  const signed = doctors.doc(key).collection('schedule').get();
  signed.then(function(ss) {
    tmpS[i] = tmpS[i] || []; // initialize the inner array

    ss.forEach(function(schedule) {
      tmpS[i].push(schedule.data());
    });

    console.log(tmpS[i])
  });
})

// tmpS will have same number of inner arrays as tmpD.length
console.log(tmpS)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to make it to `tmpS` instead of using `tmpS0`, `tmpS1` and `tmpS2` because it is dynamic it might go beyond `tmpS20`

Comment: @newbie "*I'm trying to make it to tmpS*" I'm not sure what you mean. You can still create a 2 dimensional array `tmps` like in the answer without creating variables `tmpS0`, `tmpS1` etc. But you'd have to check if `tmps[i]` is undefined before pushing it inside the loop like this: `tmps[i] =  tmps[i] || []`

Comment: I mean this `let tmps = [tmpS0, tmpS1, tmpS2];` shouldn't have to be only up to `tmpS2` so it's dynamic